# using array in condition

Tags: c, arrays

I want to check an array in a condition. Let's take this simple code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; // initializing an array
    if(array[] == {1,2,3,4,5}) // using as condition
    {
         printf("worked");
    }
    else printf("not worked");

    return 0;
}
```

But it gives an error:

```
In function 'main':|
C:\Python32\Untitled4.c|5|error: expected expression before ']' token|
||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

So how should I use an array in a condition?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a modern C compiler, at least C99, you can use a compound literal and a function to do that comparison:

```
if(memcmp(array, (int[]){1,2,3,4,5}, sizeof array) == 0) {
   printf("worked");
}
```

- Here `memcmp` (memory compare) compares the data to which the two
  pointers point.
- `(int[]){1,2,3,4,5}` is the compound literal, something with the type in `()` and then an initializer in `{ }` as you have in the declaration of your variable.
- the two arrays are converted to pointers to their first elements when used like in expressions like that

*Edit:* As Eric correctly remarks, `memcmp` is only a valid comparison if the base type of your array (here this is `int`) has no padding bits or bytes. For `int` this is uncommon these days, so what I describe is fine on usual platforms. If you'd have other, more complex, data types some day, you would have to write your own comparison function for arrays of that type.

Comment: memcmp is not a safe way to perform comparison because even basic types may have padding bits. This will work for arrays of basic types on common platforms but is not standard C in general, is not portable, is not portable, and will not work on complex types (structs with padding).

Comment: @EricPostpischil, right, please see my edit. For the downvoters, would have been nicer to tell first what you didn't like. SO is supposed to be a friendly place.

Comment: [Regarding niceness.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/08/stack-exchange-is-not-a-forum-the-role-of-niceness-on-a-qa-site/)

Answer (score 5):

This format:

```
int array[]={1,2,3,4,5};
```

Can only be used in the *initialization* or arrays or structs. This is referred to as *aggregate initialization*. This can't be used to generally represent an array.

Furthermore, you can't use `==` to compare arrays or structs in C.

To code your condition, you'll need to check each value.

Answer (score 4):

Another different example of "you can assign with `=`, but not compare with `==` is with `struct` types.

```
struct S {
    int array[5];
};

struct S a = { { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 } };
struct S b;

b = a; /* assignment ok */
if (b == a) { /* equality not ok */ }
```

> So how should I use an array in a condition?

<s>You can use [`memcmp`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcmp).</s>

```
if (memcmp(b.array, a.array, sizeof(b.array)) == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

**Edit:** Note that `memcmp` performs a byte by byte comparison of two memory locations. As Eric points out, if your object has padding bits with different values, or if your type has multiple bit representations for the same value, then `memcmp` may produce false negatives.

This issue is avoided in practice by initializing objects in a normalized way (e.g., using `memset` to `0` out the memory before doing member assignments). **Edit:** **Even so, the comparison via `memcmp` may still produce a false negative. The maximally portable way to perform the comparison is by comparing each corresponding member with each other. ([Follow the link for the gory details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11994513/315052).)**

You can create a helper function to make this easier to do:

```
/* API as memcmp, but memory treated like array of int, remainder bytes ignored */
int memcmp_int (const void *a, const void *b, size_t sz) {
    const int *aa = a;
    const int *bb = b;
    while (sz >= sizeof(int)) {
        if (*aa < *bb) return -1;
        if (*aa > *bb) return 1;
        ++aa;
        ++bb;
        sz -= sizeof(int);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Then, the code can be modified very simply:

```
if (memcmp_int(b.array, a.array, sizeof(b.array)) == 0) { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: memcmp is not a safe way to perform comparison because even basic types may have padding bits. This will work for arrays of basic types on common platforms but is not standard C in general, is not portable, and will not work on complex types (structs with padding).

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "not standard C" and "not portable"?

Comment: The C standard permits C implementations to include padding bits with objects. The values of these padding bits are not specified by the C standard. It also permits some objects to have multiple representations (different bytes in the non-padding bits may represent the same value). When you compare objects with memcmp, you are comparing all bits in the object, including padding bits and the raw encoding. You are not comparing the value of the object. memcmp can return false negatives (report unequal) when the objects in fact have equal values.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I agree with your assessment of the limitations of using `memcmp`, but that just means the technique requires special measures to avoid errors, not that it is not standard or not portable.

Comment: Of course it is not portable. The behavior of this code depends on the C implementation and produces undesired behavior on some implementations and desired behavior on others. Therefore it is not portable: It does not always work when ported. As for whether it is standard C, by the technical definition, it cannot be part of a “strictly conforming program” per C 1999 clause 4, paragraph 5 (unless the result of memcmp is discarded before it can affect any output). It can be considered (non-strictly) conforming.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: [I started a question about this point](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11994513/315052). It doesn't seem like I was the only one confused about this. I will change my answer here once I get a complete answer to my question. Thanks for raising my awareness about this issue.

Comment: That memcmp_int returns 0 if two arrays differ only in the last element.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Off by one bugs the scourge of my existence. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to loop through the array. A simple loop would look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; //initializing an array
    int iter = 0;
    for (; iter < sizeof(*array); iter++){
        printf("Iteration: %i\n", iter);
        // TOOD: Add your condition here
    }
    return 0;
}
```