# Is using memcmp on array of int strictly conforming?

Tags: c, language-lawyer

Is the following program a strictly conforming program in C? I am interested in c90 and c99 but c11 answers are also acceptable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct S { int array[2]; };

int main () {
    struct S a = { { 1, 2 } };
    struct S b;
    b = a;
    if (memcmp(b.array, a.array, sizeof(b.array)) == 0) {
        puts("ok");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In [comments to my answer in a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11993431/315052), Eric Postpischil insists that the program output will change depending on the platform, primarily due to the possibility of uninitialized padding bits. I thought the struct assignment would overwrite all bits in `b` to be the same as in `a`. But, C99 does not seem to offer such a guarantee. From Section 6.5.16.1 p2:

> In *simple assignment* (`=`), the value of the right operand is converted to the type of the assignment expression and replaces the value stored in the object designated by the left operand.

What is meant by "converted" and "replaces" in the context of compound types?

Finally, consider the same program, except that the definitions of `a` and `b` are made global. Would *that* program be a strictly conforming program?

**Edit:** Just wanted to summarize some of the discussion material here, and not add my own answer, since I don't really have one of my own creation.

- The program is not strictly conforming. Since the assignment is by value and not by representation, `b.array` may or may not contain bits set differently from `a.array`.
- `a` doesn't need to be converted since it is the same type as `b`, but the replacement is by value, and done member by member.
- Even if the definitions in `a` and `b` are made global, post assignment, `b.array` may or may not contain bits set differently from `a.array`. (There was little discussion about the padding bytes in `b`, but the posted question was not about structure comparison. c99 lacks a mention of how padding is initialized in static storage, but c11 explicitly states it is zero initialized.)
- On a side note, there is agreement that the `memcmp` is well defined if `b` was initialized with `memcpy` from `a`.

My thanks to all involved in the discussion.

Comment: Not related to padding and not applicable to the 1 and 2 values used in the question, but still in its spirit, I have found nothing preventing a sign and magnitude or ones' complement implementation which consider -0 as a redundant way to represent 0 to normalize it on assignment.

Comment: Your example in the question is still not a good one. You are not comparing the `struct` as it seems your intention but only the arrays. So in the example you give here it is still only the question if `int` has padding bits, or e.g so-called negative zeroes. These things don't happen on modern architectures. You'd really have to think of a real structure with real padding bytes (and not padding bits) such that the problem becomes relevant.

Comment: @JensGustedt: The question is specifically about `memcmp` with array of `int`, and the `struct` is used to effect the assignment into the array held by `b`.

Comment: @user315052, for arrays it would be fine with `memcpy`. `memcpy` and `memcmp` work on a byte base, those bytes seen as `unsigned char`. ` unsigned char` is the only data type that is guaranteed to not have padding bit and where all representations have distinct values.

Comment: Eric is one of a few people on SO whose opinion you can pretty much simply accept at face value where C standard language-lawyering is involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C99 §6.2.6

> §6.2.6.1 General
>
> 1 The representations of all types are unspecified except as stated in this subclause.
>
> [...]
>
> 4 [..] Two values (other than NaNs) with the same object representation compare equal, but values that compare equal may have different object representations.
>
> 6 When a value is stored in an object of structure or union type, including in a member object, the bytes of the object representation that correspond to any padding bytes take unspecified values.<sup>42)</sup>
>
> 42) Thus, for example, structure assignment need not copy any padding bits.
>
> 43) It is possible for objects x and y with the same effective type T to have the same value when they are accessed as objects of type T, but to have different values in other contexts. In particular, if == is defined for type T, then x == y does not imply that memcmp(&x, &y, sizeof (T)) == 0. Furthermore, x == y does not necessarily imply that x and y have the same value; other operations on values of type T may distinguish between them.
>
> §6.2.6.2 Integer Types
>
> [...]
>
> 2 For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign bit. There need not be any padding bits;[...]
>
> [...]
>
> 5 The values of any padding bits are unspecified.[...]

In J.1 Unspecified Behavior

> - The value of padding bytes when storing values in structures or unions (6.2.6.1).
>
> [...]
>
> - The values of any padding bits in integer representations (6.2.6.2).

Therefore there may be bits in the representation of `a` and `b` that differ while not affecting the value. This is the same conclusion as the other answer, but I thought that these quotes from the standard would be good additional context.

---

If you do a `memcpy` then the `memcmp` would always return 0 and the program would be strictly conforming. The `memcpy` duplicates the object representation of `a` into `b`.

Comment: Thanks! So, it should be safe to do a `memcmp` after a `memcpy` though, since `memcpy` copies the same bits, right?

Comment: @user315052 yes, this would be conforming; see details in the answer

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that it is strictly conforming. According to 4.5 that Eric Postpischil mentioned:

> A strictly conforming program shall use only those features of the
>   language and library  specified in this International Standard. It
>   shall not produce output dependent on any unspecified, undefined, or
>   implementation-defined behavior, and shall not exceed any  minimum
>   implementation limit.

The behavior in question is the behavior of `memcmp`, and this is well-defined, without any unspecified, undefined or implementation-defined aspects. It works on the raw bits of the representation, without knowing anything about the values, padding bits or trap representations. Thus the **result** (but not the **functionality**) of `memcmp` in this specific case depends on the implementation of the values stored within these bytes.

Footnote 43) in 6.2.6.2:

> It is possible for objects x and y with the same effective type T to
>   have the same value when they are accessed as objects of type T, but
>   to have different values in other contexts. In particular, if == is
>   defined for type T, then x == y does not imply that memcmp(&x, &y,
>   sizeof (T)) == 0. Furthermore, x == y does not necessarily imply that
>   x and y have the same value; other operations on values of type T may
>   distinguish between them.

EDIT:

Thinking it a bit further, I'm not so sure about the strictly conforming anymore because of this:

> It shall not produce output dependent on **any** unspecified [...]

Clearly the result of `memcmp` depends on the unspecified behavior of the representation, thereby fulfilling this clause, even though the behavior of `memcmp` itself is well defined. The clause doesn't say anything about the depth of functionality until the output happens.

So it is **not** strictly conforming.

EDIT 2:

I'm not so sure that it will become strictly conforming when `memcpy` is used to copy the struct. According to Annex J, the unspecified behavior happens when `a` is initialized:

```
struct S a = { { 1, 2 } };
```

Even if we assume that the padding bits won't change and `memcpy` always returns 0, it still uses the padding bits to obtain its result. And it relies on the assumption that they won't change, but there is no guarantee in the standard about this.

We should differentiate between paddings bytes in structs, used for alignment, and padding bits in specific native types like `int`. While we can safely assume that the padding bytes won't change, but only because there is no real reason for it, the same does not apply for the padding bits. The standard mentions a parity flag as an example of a padding bit. This may be a software function of the implementation, but it may as well be a hardware function. Thus there may be other hardware flags used for the padding bits, including one that changes on read accesses for whatever reason.

We will have difficulties in finding such an exotic machine and implementation, but I see nothing that forbid this. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The program can produce "ok" or nothing. If the program produces "ok" on one platform, but not on another, wouldn't that mean the output depends on something that is not well-defined?

Comment: @jxh: If the sequence of characters produced by a program is not allowed to vary from one platform to another, it would be rather difficult for any strictly-conforming program to use `rand()`.  A more helpful definition of conformance would be that a program must *meet its requirements* on any standards-compliant platform; if the above program's requirements said that it must either print "ok" or nothing, but must not output the string "Fred", the above program would be strictly-compliant by any reasonable reading of the standard [though it might exceed minimalist implementation limits].

Comment: @supercat: My comment was limited to the example program, not a generic program behavior specification.

Comment: @jxh: So was mine.  If your program could yield Undefined Behavior on any standards-compliant platform, then a standards-compliant platform could generate code which output "Fred".  Even if the sole requirement for your program was that it not output "Fred", there could exist standards-compliant platforms where your program would violate that requirement if your program invoked Undefined Behavior.  Since it doesn't invoke UB, however, all Standard-compliant implementations must generate code which abides by the requirement not to output "Fred".

Comment: @supercat: You introduced the notion about using `rand()`, which would not necessarily require the same program to generate the same output. I was explaining in my comment that if my example program was strictly conforming, it should generate the same output for all compliant compilers. The original version of this answer had said something to the effect that the program was conforming even if it might generate different output on different platforms.

Comment: @jxh: Nothing in the source code for your program says what it is required to do.  If for some reason someone wanted a program which might print "ok" or might not, but wouldn't print "Fred" in any event, the source code above would be a strictly-compliant implementation of those requirements.  If the requirement was that the program print "ok", the code above would not be a strictly-compliant implementation of that requirement.

Comment: @supercat: Hmmm... perhaps I am not explaining myself clearly. A strictly-compliant program must not depend on anything except well defined behaviors (so undefined and implementation defined behaviors are out). I am asking if my example program is such. And, I argued to the answerer that if the program was such, it would always produce the same output on all platforms.

Comment: @jxh: Under a hyper-strict interpretation of "strict compliance", almost no non-trivial program could qualify.  Compilers are required to allow a function which is called from `main` to call at least one other function, but any program that nests function calls more deeply than that would exceed a Minimum Implementation Limit.  Even if one loosens the requirements a little, I don't think it's helpful to require character-identical output in all cases.

Comment: @jxh: Consider a program which uses a `memcmp` to quickly determine if two arrays are certainly equal, and then if they're unequal will eventually use item-by-item comparisons, and will end up achieving its required objectives in any case.  I see no benefit to requiring that the program's output provide no indication of how it achieved its objective.

Comment: @supercat: I am not arguing about the utility of the definition. The definition is what it is (per the standard).