# How to compare two images by memcmp which one do x-axis flip

Tags: c++

I am writing an image processing application in C++ and need to compare images. For example, I have two arrays as below:

```
int image1[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int image2[] = {40, 30, 20, 10};
```

I would like to find a more efficient way to do comparison than a `for` loop  (like memcmp).

Comment: `memcmp` ultimately uses a loop.

Comment: this two images are equal? what are their dimensions WxH?

Comment: How do you think this can be optimized? If I have two images which are exactly the same but for one pixel at a random position, obviously I have to search the whole image in the worst case. What you could do would make sure that the data is read in the correct way (for the memory cache and for the processors vector comparison abilities) and to parallelize it. Shaves of some nanoseconds. But there is no necessity for that, simply comparing them is done in the blink of an eye if they are not extremely oversized. If you need to read and save them, this will take the longest time anyhow.

Comment: @Evgeniy, the content of images are equal. But one is upside down and mirror to another one. The dimension are 2048x2048.

Comment: preciese algorithm will need to compare all pixels, so you will need full image for-loop. but you can try to compare N random (or fixed position) pixels first to determine if your images may be different. if N random pixels are equal - make full compare for final decision.

Answer (score 1):

From your question it is not clear if you want to compare two images/int-arrays for equality or if you want to check if one of them is the flipped version of the other.

In any case you should **refrain from over-optimizing** and using functions like `memcmp`. From the complexity point of view there is no difference from a `for`-loop: **leave the optimization to your compiler, keep your code easy to read and maintain!**

To check if one array is the flipped version of the other, you can use the following code:

```
int image1[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int image2[] = {40, 30, 20, 10};
int len = 4;
bool equal = true;
for (int i = 0; i<len; i++) {
    if (image1[i] != image2[len-i-1]) {
        equal = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

---

Other thing you can do is to store the **image hash** along with the image and compare only the image hashes. It has some drawbacks though:

1. If you use the images for comparison only once, you save no time as hashing requires reading the whole array just as the direct comparison.
2. Hashing will not 100% guarantee you equality, as there are inherent collisions. Their amount depends on the quality of the hashing function used.
3. To use hashing for the flipped images, you would also need to generate the hash of a flipped version of the image and use that for comparisons.

Comment: Yes, I just comparison image only once.

Comment: Then stick to the for loop approach.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the size from somewhere, then you can `memcmp` them:

```
size_t size = 4;
int image1[] = {10, 20, 30, 40};
int image2[] = {40, 30, 20, 10};
if(!memcmp(image1, image2, sizeof(int) * size))
  //equal
```

Mind yourself though, [padding might ruin your day](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11995514/1870760) in this case.